# Why is ... $A \lor ( \neg A \land B)$ ... not ... $A \lor ( A \lor\lnot B)\,?$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have this expression:

$$A \lor ( \neg A \land B)$$

So I transformed it to:

$$ A \lor ( A \lor \neg B)$$

But my expression table says that I'm wrong! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a not:

$$A \lor (\neg A \land B)$$

is equivalent to

$$A \lor \neg (A \lor \neg B) $$

If for example $\neg B$ is true then $(\neg A  \land B)$ has to be false. The same for the case where $A$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\begin{align} A \lor (\lnot A \land B) & \equiv (A \lor \lnot A) \land (A \lor B) \\ \\ & \equiv T \land(A \lor B) \\ \\ &\equiv A\lor B\end{align}$$

I used the distributive property in the first step.